# Why I am getting invalid result?

Tags: python

```
#input is of type U-1011-13-F-CS-498 where U 1011 AND F is fixed and all are varying
import re
def validateEnrollment(eno):
    match_obj=re.findall(r'("U")\-("1011")\-("[0-99]")\-("F")\-(["CS|EC|BT"])\-("[000-999]")',eno,re.I|re.M)
    if match_obj:
        print("Your eno is valid",match_obj)

    else:
        print("Invalid eno")

eno=input("enter your enrollment number")
print("the enrollment number is",validateEnrollment(eno))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reqular expression is invalid. Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/1rfRsc/3):

```
^U-1011-\d\d-F-(CS|EC|BT)-\d\d\d$
```

**Edit:**

In Python, use this to check the input:

```
match = re.match(r'^U-1011-\d\d-F-(CS|EC|BT)-\d\d\d$', "U-1011-13-F-CS-498")
if match != None:
    return "Your eno is valid"
```